# Nodejs Redis createClient() function

Tags: node.js, redis

Can anyone solve this problem? I'm a node.js and redis beginner.

The function `createClient()` can take 2 arguments: port and host. But I'm still stuck with this problem.

```
var client = redis.createClient(); 

client.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('Redis client connected');
});
```

> Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect
>   ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
>        C:\Users\my-pc\Desktop\FINAL>node index events.js:187
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect
>   ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1128:14) Emitted 'error' event on RedisClient instance at:
>       at RedisClient.on_error (C:\Users\my-pc\Desktop\FINAL\node_modules\redis\index.js:406:14)
>       at Socket. (C:\Users\my-pc\Desktop\FINAL\node_modules\redis\index.js:279:14)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
>       at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
>       at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
>   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',   syscall: 'connect',   address: '127.0.0.1',
>   port: 6379 }

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: Redis only config on port 6379. And even in my index.js file, the app listen on port 6379 still causes this problem.

Comment: is your redis service running?

Answer (score 6):

This is a very common but simple issue whenever i had also started working with docker multiple local containers.

See, you have created a node app and also a redis server, but both are separated, you didn't build any communication between them, that's why you are facing this type of problems.

Now, first you have to build a connection between the node app and redis-server so that they can communicate between then.

For doing this, just simply follow the instructions, hopefully this will solve your issues.

Step-1: For building connection between multiple local containers, you have two options to do this,

```
* Use docker CLI's networking features.
* Or, simply use docker-compose to solve the issue, i prefer docker-compose and i will show how to do this using docker-compose.
```

Docker-compose: Compose is a tool for defining and running multi-container docker applications. [Overview of docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/#:%7E:text=Compose%20is%20a%20tool%20for,the%20services%20from%20your%20configuration.&text=Run%20docker%2Dcompose%20up%20and,and%20runs%20your%20entire%20app.)

Step-2: Make a docker-compose .yml file in your project directory, named by "docker-compose.yml"

Step-3: Write the following code in your "docker-compose.yml" file:

```
version: "2.0"
services: 
  redis-server: 
    image: "redis"
  node-app: 
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "8080:8080"
```

Step-4: Inside your redis.createClient() funstion, simply pass your host and port parameters in index.js file

```
const client = redis.createClient({
    host: "redis-server",
    port: 6379
});
```

Step-5: Build and run your docker container using docker-compose from docker-compose CLI

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Step-6: And finally, open your browser and hit the following URL:

```
localhost:8080
```

Comment: OP didn't mention anything about Docker so it is less likely that issue is related to Docker.

Answer (score 5):

just for your information (I wasted this evening with that)

This does not work (it defaults connecting to localhost:6379 whatever you put in the url):

```
const redisURL = "redis://foo.bar.org:6379"
redis.createClient( redisURL )
```

but this DOES WORK

```
redis.createClient( {url: redisURL} )
```

Hope I saved your time.

Comment: Ugh..  thanks for the tip.  I just wasted to much time on this also.  Sounds like bug.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the error code being 'ECONNREFUSED' are you positive that you're actually running a redis-server on localhost and port 6379 before you try to connect the client?

Comment: I forgot to turn on the sever.

Comment: Everything's OK now.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add `socket` and it will magically work.

```js
const client = redis.createClient({
  socket: {
    host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
    port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
  },
});
```

You are welcome!

Answer (score -1):

I have faced a similar issue when i started with Redis on nodejs.

The problem is the redis server connection has not been established yet, but still you are using your connection. You can use async and await until your connection is established.

You can use the following code:

```js
var client = redis.createClient();

client.connect().then(async () => {
  client.on('error', err => {
    console.log('Error ' + err);
    logger.info("Error is her");
  });
});
```

I hope your issue is solved. If not, You can revert to this thread